# How should we tag the Pokemon Mystery Dungeon series?

Tags: discussion, tags, pokemon

[I just asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12099/good-pokemon-for-the-zero-isle-south-dungeon) the first question on the site regarding the Pokemon Mystery Dungeon series. How should we go about tagging the games? Some information:

- There are currently 5 games that have been released everywhere, and 3 that have only been released in Japan
- **Blue Rescue Team** is for the DS, and **Red Rescue Team** is for the GBA, and both are the same "generation"
- **Explorers of Time**, **Explorers of Darkness**, and **Explorers of Sky** are all for the DS, and are all the same "generation"
- The games that have only been released in Japan are WiiWare games, and are named (loose English translations):


  - **Keep Going! Blazing Adventure Squad! (Japanese: ポケモン不思議のダンジョン すすめ！炎の冒険団)**
  - **Let's Go! Stormy Adventure Squad! (Japanese: ポケモン不思議のダンジョン いくぞ！嵐の冒険団)**
  - **Go For It! Light Adventure Squad! (Japanese: ポケモン不思議のダンジョン めざせ！光の冒険団)**

First of all, should we tag the series as `pmd` or `pokemon-mystery-dungeon` (or perhaps something else)? Secondly, how would we go about tagging questions about specific games, or specific generations of the games?

Comment: Related: [Jackpot](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/777/85 "On tagging the non-Mysterious Dungeon games").

Answer (score 1):

- [pokemon-rescue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rescue)

  - [pokemon-rescue-blue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rescue-blue)
  - [pokemon-rescue-red](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-rescue-red)
- [pokemon-explorers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-explorers)

  - [pokemon-explorers-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-explorers-time)
  - [pokemon-explorers-dark](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-explorers-dark)
  - [pokemon-explorers-sky](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-explorers-sky)
- [pokemon-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-adventure)

  - [pokemon-adventure-blazing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-adventure-blazing) (25 chars exactly! phew.)
  - [pokemon-adventure-stormy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-adventure-stormy)
  - [pokemon-adventure-light](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon-adventure-light)

Comment: __TAG OVERFLOW__

Comment: Also, how about referring to the series in general? `pokemon-mystery-dungeon`?

Comment: I'm not sure there is much value in having a tag for each individual game: like the "main" Pokémon games, the differences are minimal. If anyone has a question only valid for one particular game in the series, it's almost certainly going to be something like "What is the difference between my game and the others in this series", where the general tag works just fine. The only potential exception here may be Sky: it was released after Time/Dark, and I think there are a few new things in there (but I don't know what exactly, since I haven't gotten around to buying and playing that one yet...)